# Trouble importing Excel time Duration data into R (with GUI EZR)

Tags: r, excel, date, duration, lubridate

Tearing my hair out on this one. Took me hours just to get rJava up and running  (because mac OS X el capitan was not wanting to play nice with Java) in order to load excel-specific data importing packages etc. But in the end this hasn't helped my problem, and I'm just about at my wits end. Please help.

Basic situation is this:

Have simple excel data of time durations, over a span of a couple of years. So the two columns I'm importing are the time(duration) and year(2016,2017 etc).

In Excel the data is formatted as [h]:mm:ss so it displays correctly (data is related to number of hours worked in a month, so typically something like 80:xx:xx ~ 120:xx:xx). I'm aware that in excel, despite the cells being formatted as above, and only showing the relevant period of hours, that in reality excel has appended an (irrelevant, arbitrary) date to this hours data. I have searched and searched and found no way around this limitation in the way excel handles dates/times/durations.

I import this data into R via the "import data -> import from excel data set" menu item in R commander GUI, not the console.

However when importing the data into R, the data displays as a single number e.g. approx. 110 hrs is converted to 4.xxxxx, not as hh:mm:ss. So when running analyses and generating plots etc, instead of the actual (meaningful) 110:xx:xx type data being displayed, a completely meaningless 4.xxxxxx is displayed.

If I change the formatting of the excel cells to display the date as well as the time rather than use the [h]:mm:ss cell formatting, R erroneously interprets the data to something equally useless, like 1901/02/04 05:23 am

I have installed and loaded a variety of packages such as xlsx, XLConnect, lubridate etc but it hasn't made any difference to how R interprets the excel data on import, from the GUI at least.

Please tell me how do I either

a) edit the raw data to a format that R will understand as a time duration (and nothing but a time duration) in hh:mm:ss format, or

b) format the current data from within R after importing, so that it displays the data in the correct way rather than a useless number or arbitrary date/time?

[Please note: I can use the console, when given the commands etc needed to be executed. But I need to find a solution that ultimately will allow the data to be imported and/or manipulated from within the GUI, not from typing a bunch of commands into the console, as the end user (not me) has zero programming ability and cannot use a console, and will only ever be using R via the GUI.]

Answer (score 0):

Is your code importing the data from excel as seconds?

```
library(lubridate)
duration <- lubridate::as.duration(400000)
as.numeric(duration, "hours")
```

111.1111

```
as.numeric(duration, "days")
```

4.62963

```
seconds_to_period(400000)
```

"4d 15H 6M 40S"

Comment: Seems it must be importing it as days, as all the data in the "hours" column is in the 3.x ~ 4.x range